# How to chrome web store validate manifest.json

Tags: json, validation, google-chrome, file-upload

I interest in developer dashboard of chrome web store 
when I try to upload text file name manifest.json but inner file doesn't json format
I know that google uses any means to check the file structure
thank for suggest

Comment: Can you post the contents of your current manifest.json? It's not Chrome Web Store's JSON validator that's likely broken.

Comment: Ok Marc I doesn't tell the chrome web store json validator is broken
but  I would like to adopt the chrome web store checks json format to use in my own projects. Sorry if the question is not clear

Answer (score 5):

Before uploading your extension to the webstore, it is really better to test by loading your extension as an "unpacked extension", which you can do by visiting chrome://extensions, expanding "Developer Mode" if it isn't already expanded, and then clicking "Load unpacked extension..."

Loading your extension will allow you to test it and discover issues, long before publishing it to test accounts or to other users. The [Chrome extension developers' guide - manifest format](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html) documents what is permissible in the manifest. It is also necessary for the manifest to be standard JSON.

Also, I should point out that the Chrome webstore may disallow well-formatted code if it violates the terms (e.g. violating the branding guidelines or seeming to represent a  website you don't own).

Comment: Is there a tool that can validate the manifest statically, so that it can be deployed as part of a CI pipeline?

Answer (score 5):

I found that Chrome store will not accept manifest.json including "// comment", but Chrome developer mode accepts.

I copy and paste from here, and "// Optional" is added to my manifest.json file.
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest.html

Maybe Chrome developer mode should also reject the comments?

Comment: It does not accept multiline comments too.
"/* Test comment */"
while chrome Chrome developer mode accepts it.